# Angular 13 ng serve NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID

Tags: angular, upgrade, angular13

I've upgraded my application from Angular 11 to 13. Upgrading from 11 from 12 worked fine, but now I have some problems going from 12 to 13.
If I try to run `ng serve` or `ng build` I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
```

I've upgraded my libraries but I keep getting this error.
This is the error log:

```
[error] Error: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
    at Object.code ([...]\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\vocabularies\core\id.js:6:15)
    at keywordCode ([...]\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:454:13)
at [...]\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:222:17
    at CodeGen.code ([...]\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:439:13)
    at CodeGen.block ([...]\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:568:18)
    at iterateKeywords ([...]\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:219:9)
    at groupKeywords ([...]\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:208:13)
    at [...]\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\validate\index.js:192:13
    at CodeGen.code ([...]\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:439:13)
    at CodeGen.block ([...]\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\ajv\dist\compile\codegen\index.js:568:18)
```

and this is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.34",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.11",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "mat-currency-format": "0.0.7",
    "ng-inline-svg": "13.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xml-beautify": "^1.2.3",
    "xml-formatter": "^2.6.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "~13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.5.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.11.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.29.0",
    "change-case": "^4.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "globby": "^11.0.3",
    "initials": "^3.1.1",
    "inquirer": "^8.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter": "0.0.23",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "xml-beautifier": "^0.4.3"
}
```

Comment: Did you update using `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12`  or manually?

Comment: @ArifKhan I've used ng update, I've followed the instructions in the angular update guide

Comment: An update to angular 14, may be fixed this issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the lint schematics

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@next
```

Comment: Running this upgraded it to 14.0.0-alpha.4, but I keep having the same error

Comment: try angulu/cli version 12 instead of 13

Comment: I need to use 13, they asked us to do so

Comment: then you have to upgrade to angular 14

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, I have to use angular 13

Comment: have you tried removing the node modules and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

install schematics by deleting package lock and node_modules then running npm I and ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@next

Comment: I've tried this but I keep getting that error

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It seems you have custom schematics in your app, please check the below issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22637